# how to resolve error comes after the signout through devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class HomeController < WebController
  layout "home"

  def index
    binding.pry
    user = current_user.places
  end
end
```

when I was login through it then it login successfully, but if I logout and 
I redirect to again to this and give error because the `current_user` is empty then how should i use devise for sign out and maintaining the `current_user`

```
error [undefined method `places' for nil:NilClass]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access current_user when you are not logged in. You can either only give access to HomeController to logged in users, by adding atuhenticate_user filter to your HomeController.

```
class HomeController < WebController
  layout "home"
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    binding.pry
    user = current_user.places
  end
end
```

Or you can not call current_users.places when user is not logged in.

```
class HomeController < WebController
  layout "home"

  def index
    binding.pry
    user = current_user.places if current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: the 2nd one was working but the first one is not it will redirect me to the default view of devise ..... any ways thanks ....